# Facing Error while injecting second service into Controller AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having **two services**: 
**A**: accountService
**B**: invoiceService

**Controllers:** 
**A**: TicketController.
**B**: InvoiceController.

below is the definition of TicketController:

```
angular.module("app").controller('TicketController', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', 'uploadManager', 'ticketService', 'accountService', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, uploadManager, ticketService, accountService) {

}]);
```

In Above controller accountService is working perfectly fine. 
but when I inject the same accountService to invoice controller it throws error.
Below is the definition of invoiceController:

```
angular.module("app").controller('InvoiceController', ['accountService', 'invoiceService', function (accountService, invoiceService) {

}]);
```

when i execute it, it throws error:
[Error when I execute the above code for invoiceController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmDee.png)

can anyone help what could be the problem?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think there is an error in the accountService. Could you provide its code?

Comment: Have you added all the dependencies required for it?

Comment: show the index.html file

Answer (score 1):

The code we can see looks perfectly fine.

Make sure that in your `index.html` that you load the files in the right order. If you try to load `InvoiceController` before you defined the `accountService` you will get this error.